# Xcode/iOS5: How to set UTF-8 into a POST function for correct encoding?

Tags: iphone, utf-8, encode

I'd like to encode my message correctly. When I post my data via PHP to my email, some characters look wrong (in german ü, ö, ä look like u, o, a). How do I correctly encode my message in UTF-8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I right if I assume that you want to send an NSString to a server?
Try using NSString's `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` before generating the URL.

Comment: Jenox, can you give me an example?

Comment: `NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/index.php?x=%@", [@"äöüß" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`

Comment: Can I use your code in this case too? `post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"name=%@", textFieldName.text];`

Comment: It should be `[textFieldName.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`